# Options for Bulk Download of Satellite Imagery

Tags: data, imagery, download

I am looking for some sources of Satellite imagery that I can bulk-download for offline use with mobile apps. I am willing to pay, but so far I am not finding any good solutions out there.

Something similar to Google Satellite image tiles.

Looking for providers that provide tile URLs in a format like the following:

```
http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg
```

Does anyone have any good providers out there for this sort of requirement?

Comment: Which kind of data? Which region? Which resolution (spatial, termporal, spectral)? So far it is quite unclear what you need. You´re looking for something like Googles Satelite-images?

Comment: @HimBromBeere - I am needing tiles of the whole world. Yes, something just like Google Satellite imagery.